# Google Map API v3 not showing

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I tried to add this script to my html page: **(its a temporary link, it is removed)** (this script works fine alone, it is not showing the map when I add it to my html)

It calculates the distance and shows the result but the map is not showing.

The city textbox below departure is address1 and the city textbox below arrival is address2. The map is suppose to show in the div tag with id: map_canvas but it is not showing. I tried adding and removing form tag, changing the layout and so on but nothing worked.

I would be glad if anyone could help me fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: What script? If your question is to be useful to anyone in the future, then you should not remove references as doing so leaves the question meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your height-setting. Try

```
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:500px;"></div>
```

See also this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3fFg/)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `width` and `height` property of your `map_canvas` to absolute values like `400px`.

Can't tell you exactly why, but it will show up then. Probably because x percent of nothing (because initially there is no content in the div) equals nothing, and the div doesn't refresh when you add the map to it.